# Simplify integration result with conditions

Tags: integral-equations, conditional

Let's say I have integral

```
Integrate[1/(1 + (f^2/B^2)), {f, 0, Infinity}]
```

The result is

$$\text{ConditionalExpression}\left[\frac{\pi }{2 \sqrt{\frac{1}{B^2}}},\Im\left(B^2\right)\neq 0\lor \Re\left(B^2\right)\geq 0\right] $$
How can I agree to these conditions and have the Mathematica simplify this result to: 
$$B\frac{\pi}{2}$$
Or is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just specify the [`Assumptions`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html) for the [`Integrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html):

```
Integrate[1/(1 + (f^2/B^2)), {f, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> B > 0]
(* (B π)/2 *)
```

Comment: Perfect! Surfed through help for 30mins but didn't find that info. Also your too fast ;) I can't accept for the next 11mins.

Comment: @ELEC I'd recommend to read other answers too, so you can choose the one, that's suit you the most.

Answer (score 1):

```
Integrate[1/(1 + (f^2/B^2)), {f, 0, Infinity}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

> ```
> π/(2 Sqrt[1/B^2])
> ```